How to configure ollama setup exe from its source code
I was required to install Ollama setup exe from the source code in windows
I found the steps as

Note: The Windows build for Ollama is still under development.
First, install required tools:
MSVC toolchain - C/C++ and cmake as minimal requirements
Go version 1.22 or higher
MinGW (pick one variant) with GCC. MinGW-w64 MSYS2
The ThreadJob Powershell module: Install-Module -Name ThreadJob -Scope
CurrentUser
Then, build the ollama binary:
$env:CGO_ENABLED="1"
go generate ./...
go build .


I completed above steps but getting error in CMake.
Details of software in my system:

go version
MinGw software version 13.2.0
cmake version 3.29.0-rc2
visual studio 2022
system is 64bit

The error is
cmake version 3.29.0-rc2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
llm\generate\generate_windows.go:3: running "powershell": exit status 1

